# A priori estimates to $u_t - \Delta u = u^2$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

My research is now considering the a priori estimates on the equation
$$
\begin{cases}u_t - \Delta u = u \min(u,c) \\
u(0,y) = u(1,y)\\
u_x(0,y) = u_x(1,y)\\
\partial_n u(x,0) = \partial_n u(x,1) = 0
\end{cases}$$ on a 2-dimensional periodic domain $[0, 1]^2$, where $c > 0$ is some fixed given constant. I try to do inner product of the whole equation with $u$:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt}|u|_{L^2}^2 + \|u\|^2_{H^1} = \langle u\min(u,c) , u \rangle.
$$
It seems that I have no way to bound the right hand side in the following form: $$
\bigg|\int u^2\min(u,c)\bigg| \leq \epsilon \|u\|^2_{H^1} + C|u|^2_{L^2} + C,$$ because the integral looks like $\int |u|^3 = |u|_{L^3}^3$ and it has exponent to the 3; while the RHS has only 2. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: If $u$ depends only on $t$, the boundary conditions are satisfied and you get $u_t=u^2$ (letting $c \to \infty$ which blows up in finite time.

Comment: Dear Giorgio, of course you are right, but (maybe I am thinking too simply?) is not probably the whole point of the right-hand side precisely to avoid a blow up by cutting off at *fixed* level $c$?

Comment: Hi Giorgio and Hannes, I tried something and posted it as the answer, would you mind taking a look at it?

Comment: @Hannes yes, true. I want only to say that one cannot find a bound independent of $c$.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a way to show it, basically by separating the space and consider where $A^+ := \{u>0\}$ and $A^- := \{u<0\}$. Then the RHS reads
\begin{equation}
\int u^2 \min(u,c) = \int_{\{u\geq 0\}} +   \int_{\{u<0\}} \\
= (I) + (II)
\end{equation}
$(I)$ term is a good term because when $u \geq 0$, $|u^2\min(u, c)| \leq c|u|^2$ and so $|(I)| \leq c|u|^2_{L^2}$. $(II)$ term looks bad but notice that the integrand $u^3$ is negative when $u < 0$, and so we can safely move it to the left:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} |u|_{L^2}^2 + \|u\|_{H^1}^2 - (II) \leq c|u|_{L^2}^2, \text{where } (II) < 0.
\end{equation}
In particular,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} |u|_{L^2}^2 \leq c|u|_{L^2}^2.
\end{equation}
We are good with the $L_t^\infty(0,T; L_x^2)$ bound for $u$.